# flutter: how to add a loading (ios style) in front of the page?

Tags: flutter

I'm new in flutter. I want a `loading` animation (iOS style) in front of the page. I have searched for flutter loading [api](https://pub.dev/packages/loading_animations) but isn't what I want. How can I achieve it? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has a property called barrierDismissible that if you set as false, the user won't be able to close or interact with the screen outside of it.

```
void _openLoadingDialog(BuildContext context) {
showDialog(
barrierDismissible: false,
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return AlertDialog(
    content: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Once you're done with the API loading, call Navigator.pop(context); to dismiss the dialog.

To prevent the user from clicking the back button on the Dialog, dismissing it, envelop your Scaffold inside a WillPopScope widget and implement the onWillPop function.

```
 @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    enter code here return WillPopScope(
       child: Scaffold(
       body: Container(),
    ) ,
    onWillPop: _onBackButton
  );
}

 Future<bool> _onBackButton() {
 // Implement your logic
 return Future.value(false);
 }
```

If you return false on it, the user won't be able to press the back button. So use any logic you desire, e.g 'If I'm loading return false, otherwise return true'.

or you can use Full-screen loader: Best solution to display a full screen loader is to use package [this](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_loader)